# A meta-mathematical question related to Hilbert tenth problem

Tags: mathematical-philosophy, metamathematics, nt.number-theory, lo.logic

I am reading Bjorn Poonen's very nice survey on Hilbert's Tenth problem
([http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/uniform.pdf](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/uniform.pdf)), and while I believe I understand the mathematics well, I have widespread difficulties with the meta-mathematics of these questions. To illustrate them, and to ask a question that is answerable and whose answer might be helpful for me, let me focus on one little passage of this paper, that concerns not directly Matthiasevich's theorem that the tenth problem has a negative solution
but an older, weaker version :

**"[...] the work of K. Gödel, A. Church, and A. Turing in the 1930s made it clear that there was no algorithm for solving the [...] problem of deciding the truth of first-order sentences over $\mathbb{Z}$".** (page 6)

> What does that assertion exactly mean?

I understand well what an algorithm is and what a first-order sentence in arithmetic is.
The difficult word in the quoted sentence is "truth".

Here is my tentative interpretation. Define a "platonist" as someone
who believes that natural integers actually exist and that first order sentences about them are either absolutely true or absolutely false. I am such a person. So for a platonist,
the passage quoted above would mean: "there is no Turing machine that take a first-order sentence as input and produces the output TRUE or FALSE according to wether the sentence is absolutely true or absolutely false." Ok. The problem is that this interpretation makes
sense only for a platonist. I am not going to name names here, but I know very good mathematicians that are not platonists in the above sense.

> Is there another (weaker) interpretation of the quoted sentence, that would make sense for pretty all mathematicians?

Or, is the statement from Poonen's paper simply rejected as non-sensical by those
non-platonist mathematicians ?

I have in mind Gödel's incompleteness theorem itself, that comes in two versions: one for everyone, that says that there is a first-order arithmetical sentence
that can not be proved nor disproved in, say, PA; and one stronger version
for platonists that says that there is a first-order arithmetical sentence, that cannot be proved in, say, PA, but that is nevertheless true. But for the theorem of Gödel-Church-Turing
quoted by Poonen I don't see what would be the version acceptable by everyone.

**Edit**: Many people seem to have great difficulties to understand my question. I am not sure I understand why. Let me try to explain it more from the "philosophical" point of view.
I think anyone would agree that it is not self-evident that a first-order statement
about numbers makes sense, and is either true or false independently of the system of axioms
we choose. (Surely, a statement about sets does not necessary make sense, like
"is the set of all sets an element of itself".) Actually, I do believe that any first-order statement about numbers makes sense, but for me this is like a religious belief, not something
I would feel authorized to use in a serious mathematical theorem. Basically, like most number theorists I suppose, I work with ZF with the enumerable axiom of choice, and I feel pain in the stomach when occasionally I need to use the full axiom of choice or Grothendieck's axiom of universes (and in general, we convince ourselves that they are just used "to simplify the exposition", and that they could be avoided at the cost of just a lost in elegance).
So when I see a statement like the one in boldface above, as a platonist I understand what it means, but I wonder if it is a reasonable statement that I can agree with with
non-platonist colleagues.

Comment: I don't really see what this has to do with platonism, but I guess this might be because the meaning of the term is at issue here. If platonism requires one to reject Godel's incompleteness theorem, the whole thing seem moot; on the other hand, if platonism means believing that the integers exist while allowing that any axiomatic system that fits the integers also has other models, then I don't see the problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Joël: Your last paragraph makes me think that the sort of non-platonistic assertion you seek, corresponding to "truth in $\mathbb{N}$ is undecidable," would just be "$PA$ is undecidable." That statement refers only to the undecidability of a syntactic theory, and doesn't involve any semantic notions. And if one is feeling platonistic, the undecidability of truth in $\mathcal{N} := \langle\mathbb{N},0,1,+,\cdot\rangle$, or in other words of the theory $\mathrm{Th}(\mathcal{N})$, follows from the facts that $\mathcal{N}\models PA$ (hence $PA\subseteq\mathrm{Th}(\mathcal{N})$) ...

Comment: (cont'd) and that $PA$ is an essentially undecidable theory. But as Thierry wonders, perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: BTW, the original link in the question points to a different Poonen paper than was intended. It should be http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/h10_notices.pdf.

Comment: @Thierry: Platonism doesn't require one to reject Godel's theorem. Why should it? Godel was a platonist. For a post-Godel platonist, every assertion about natural number is either true or false, simply 
no system of axioms (satisfying some conditions I don't recall)
is strong enough to allow to deduce all truths. 

Comment: @Ed: I am not sure I really understand your comments. I am seeking an assertion, that a formalist would not reject as meaningless, corresponding to (1) "there is no algorithm for solving the problem of deciding the truth of first-order sentences over \mathbb{Z|", not (2) "truth in \mathbb{N} is undecidable". The truth is that, platonist or not, I don't know what (2) means, but it doesn't look like it says the same thing as (1). "Undecidibale" is something about proof in a given system of axioms, not about algorithms, no?
Can you explain? 

Comment: Any yes/no problem might be algorithmically undecidable, and I'm using that term generally, not necessarily in a formal system context. E.g. Poonen is talking about the undecidability of the problem "Given first-order $\phi$, is it true in the structure $\mathbb{Z}$?" (Or, as in my harmless switcheroo, $\mathbb{N}$.) A better term for the more restricted notion you have in mind is perhaps "formal undecidability" (not coincidentally, as in the title of Goedel's 1931 paper referring to "formal unentscheidbare" sentences). So, on this terminology, ...

Comment: @Joel: that's the way I understood it, I just wasn't sure if it was your interpretation of it. I'm still not sure what your question is about, though.

Comment: when Goedel established the syntactic incompleteness of (something like) $PA$, he was establishing that there are "formally undecidable" sentences for $PA$. But this is a different (though related) matter than whether or not there is an algorithm which decides what is provable in the theory (i.e. whether it is a decidable theory or not). So, to restate my previous comments, Poonen is pointing out that the theory $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{Z})$ is an undecidable one; i.e. there is no algorithm for deciding which are the true sentences in that structure. What my earlier comments ...

Comment: were getting at is that this follows from the fact that $PA$ is essentially undecidable. And that (or at least the weaker fact that $PA$ is undecidable), was established by Church, building off of Goedel's incompleteness theorems, and ultimately that explains Poonen's remark. If I'd anticipated writing these further comments, I would've just written an answer initially instead of a comment :-) I hope I've clarified something.

Comment: Ed, Thanks for your explanation, and it would be nice if you wrote an
answer from them eventually. I am not quite there yet. My problem comes from the fact that I am not familiar with your terminology.
So I understand from your comments that you call a theory (a set of statements) undecidable if there is no algorithm  to recognize wether a statement is in the set or not. You call a statement "formally 
undecidable" w.r.t to a given system of axioms if the statement can 
not be proved nor disproved using that given system of axioms. Am I right? Now the main thing I don't understand is...




Comment: What do you mean by $Th(\mathbb{Z})$? Is there the "set of true (first-order) statement about integers? But then, what does that mean, for someone who is not a platonist?

Comment: The structure $\langle\mathbb Z,+,\cdot\rangle$ is a mathematical object as any other, and so is the satisfaction relation $\mathbb Z\models\phi$, whose usual inductive definition you can find in any textbook on mathematical logic. $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb Z)$ is then the set of all sentences $\phi$ such that $\mathbb Z\models\phi$. This does not have anything to do with any philosophical interpretation of truth, this is a mathematical construction, which can be carried out in a fairly weak fragment of ZF. It all comes down to the fact that the integers form a set.

Comment: Emil: can you please give me a reference for the meaning of that notation $\mathbb{Z}\ ? \ \phi$ ? I sincerely have no idea of what it can mean. (I don't know how is it called nor how one produces it in latex by the way).


Comment: @Joël: See e.g. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic/Predicate_Logic/Satisfaction .

Comment: Some positive natural numbers certainly exist. It is obvious if one looks at one's bank statement. I voted to close because the discussion does not make sense in my opinion.  

Comment: I personally have a non-platonic view on non-platonic mathematicians. I think they do not exist. 

Comment: And your opinion is relevant because...?

Comment: @Joёl: ... because I can vote to close your question. 

Comment: Joёl, any mathematical theorem T is something that your non-platonist colleagues can agree with, as long as your non-platonist colleagues understand that what is being asserted is, "T is a theorem of ZFC."  This is why we don't have to settle philosophical debates in order to do math.  We all agree what the theorems are.  It's just that platonists take all the theorems at face value, and the formalists have to revert to the "T is a theorem" format for T's that they feel queasy about taking at face value.  The word "truth" here presents no special problems; it is easily formalized in ZFC.

Comment: In particular, you don't have to "believe" in $\mathbb Z$ or sets in order to write down formal sentences in the first-order language of set theory and verify that the sentences follow formally from the axioms of ZFC.  You don't need to know what Th($\mathbb Z$) "means" in order to manipulate it correctly and agree that Poonen's statement is a theorem.  And agreeing on the theorems is what matters for mathematical practice.

Comment: @Mark. This is exactly what I thought. 

Comment: @Timothy: I understand what you're saying. This is a perfectly accurate summary of the debate between realists and formalists
and this apply to most theorems. But this doesn't apply to the 
statement in boldface in my question. Let me be more specific:
you say one doesn't need to know what $Th(\mathbb{Z})$ "means"
to manipulate it formally. Right. But you need a formal definition
that you can manipulate. The problem is that I have not seen one.
You seem to want to define $Th(\mathbb{Z})$ as the set 
of first-order sentence in number theory that are provable under ZFC 
in the standard...
 



Comment: ...model. But if you do that, there will be sentences not in $Th(\mathbb{Z})$ whose negation is also not in $Th(\mathbb{Z})$.
Then the statement in boldface in my question becomes meaningless
because it does not specify what the algorithm should output with such a sentence as input. (If one interprets the requirement
as saying TALSE for an input  in $Th(\mathbb{Z})$, saying FALSE
for an input whose negation is in $Th(\mathbb{Z})$, and not ending for the other sentecmes, then the assertion in BOLDFACE becomes clearly false.) 

Comment: @Timothy, and later @Ed and Emil.
Now if you define $Th(\Z)$ not using ZFC, but as in the reference,
Emil gives me, then you don't have the problem above... but the definition of $TH(\Z)$ only makes sense if you're a super-platonist.
Let me quote form the reference Emil gave me: "A model is an interpretation for a predicate language. It consists of two parts: a domain and interpretation function.[...]A domain is a non-empty set".
The model are in turn used to define satisfaction, and $Th(\mathbb{Z})$ is defined as the set of sentence satisfied by the model $\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: But nowhere in that reference is ZFC mentioned. Set are taken 
at the intuitive level, which means that there are an implicit but obvious (super)-platonist assumption.


Comment: @Mark. Materialism and empiriocriticism? What a bad book! 
It's funny that you talk about the Moral Police, because you 
remembered me of the cops in "the duke of hazard" (everyone has the cultural references he can, sorry): intervention without the slightest idea of what is going on. Since you didn't notice, I have said several times here that I was a platonist (in the restricted sense defined in y question). Several people I am arguing with say they are not, and the question I ask them if what meaning they give then to the statement in boldface. In this sequence of comments
they have not.




Comment: been able to give a answer so far (there are more promising attempts in the formal answers, but as you can see they need serious cir convolutions.)

Comment: @Joël: Why would the reference mention ZFC? You don’t normally mention ZFC when you are, say, proving the intermediate value theorem. This is the usual practice in mathematics: you don’t explain in detail your background theory unless its details are directly relevant to the argument, otherwise it’s just a confusing distraction. You can take sets at the intuitive level in the definition if you are so inclined, but you can also take it as a formal definition in whatever set theory are you working in, such as ZFC.

Comment: @Emil: In a textbook of elementary logic, which is used to define ZFC,
I doubt that it is implicit that ZFC is the background theory.
Now, if you define T being "T is True" (resp. False) as T (resp. non-T) provable in ZFC, the statement about the algorithm becomes false. If you define "T is True" as "T is provable in ZFC" but breaking symmetry, "T is false" as the countrary of "T" is true, then there will be no algorithm (that's a special case
of Davis's answer) but 1) why don't you say so (I asked about this point several times)?2) in what does it help to use a model in ZF
instead of just PA?

Comment: I give up. I have honestly no idea what is it that you actually want.

Comment: 3) this notion is not only different but clashes with the ones commonly used: for example the realization Q in PA of the assertion in the meta-language that there is no proof of the consistency of PA
(or ZF, or ZFC, yoo choose) will be considered as true not only by full platonists like Goedel (who believes that *any* first-order sentence about numbers is meaningful and either true or false)...

Comment: ...but also by most formalists
(which are actually low-level platonists in the sense they believe in the meaningfullness of some set of sentences with simple form, depending on the individual - for exemple almost all formalists believes that a sentence with no quantificator (that is an operation like 2*1000=500+1500 is either true or false), Conway being a notable counter-example). While with the proposed definition, Q will be false.  


Comment: @Joël: No, I do not define Th(N) to be theorems provable in ZFC. Th(N) is defined to be the set of first-order sentences that are satisfied by N. Satisfiability is defined inductively. $\forall x \phi(x)$ is satisfied by N if for all $x$ in N, $\phi(x)$ is satisfied by N, and so on. All this takes place in some set-theoretic metatheory, which as you point out doesn't have to be formalized in ZFC, but ZFC suffices. It certainly helps in practice to at least pretend to be a platonist to get the formalization right, but you don't need to be.

Comment: I find Paul Cohen's book "Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis" especially clear on this kind of questions. Here are some excepts (which are, in my humble opinioon, particularly striking): http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~gaillapy/DIVERS/Cohen-truth/cohen-truth-110802a.pdf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a general "trick" for handling all issues of this sort.  Take any mathematical theorem that a platonist regards as meaningful.  Formalize it as a formal theorem T in ZFC.  The formalist will now accept the sentence, "ZFC proves T."

Here, the only potentially confusing concept is that of truth.  But to say that some first-order sentence of arithmetic is true just means that it is satisfied by the structure $\mathbb N$.  The satisfaction relation, like all ordinary mathematics, is readily defined set-theoretically, as you can see in any textbook on logic.  So the nonexistence of the algorithm in question can be expressed as a first-order sentence of set theory, and the formalist will agree that this sentence is a theorem of ZFC.

For some kinds of finitistic statements, the formalist doesn't have to do this little dance of translating "true" into formal set-theoretic terms and replacing "T" with "ZFC proves T."  For example, in the sentence, "It is true that ZFC proves T," the formalist can use his "native" understanding of the word "true" and doesn't have to convert "ZFC proves T" into an arithmetic statement S and use the set-theoretic definition of truth to get a set-theoretic assertion whose ZFC-theoremhood he can agree with.  But the little dance is always available as an option.

**EDIT:** Reading various comments to the original question and to other answers, I see that something more may need to be said about the satisfaction relation, even though it is standard textbook material.  To say that a first order sentence $\phi$ is true, or that it belongs to $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N)$, means that it is satisfied by $\mathbb N$, where satisfiability is defined inductively.  For example, $\exists x: \phi(x)$ is satisfied by $\mathbb N$ if there exists $x\in \mathbb N$ such that $\phi(x)$ is satisfied by $\mathbb N$.  Further details may be found [here](https://planetmath.org/SatisfactionRelation).

Now, you might complain that in order to "make sense" of the satisfiability relation, you have to "make sense" of $\mathbb N$.  However, you don't have to believe in $\mathbb N$ as some kind of platonically existing thing in order to correctly manipulate *sentences about* $\mathbb N$.  Any sufficiently powerful set-theoretic meta-theory will suffice to carry out the definition of $\mathbb N$ and the satisfaction relation.  ZFC is the standard choice but you could use something else if you prefer.  A way to assert the existence of $\mathbb N$ in the first-order language of set-theory is as follows: $$\exists x:(\emptyset \in x \wedge \forall y\in x: (y\cup\lbrace y\rbrace\in x))$$
Here I've used various abbreviations, e.g., $\emptyset\in x$ expands formally to $\exists z : (z\in x \wedge \neg \exists w: (w\in z))$.  Similar but more complicated formalizations can be produced for "set of first-order sentences of arithmetic" and "$\mathbb N$ satisfies $\phi$."  As long as you know the axioms and rules of inference for ZFC, you can verify that the existence of $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N)$ is provable in ZFC.  (**Note:** This is NOT the same as saying that every true sentence of arithmetic is provable in ZFC, which is absolutely false!)  And once you have $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N)$, you can simply interpret "x is true" as $x\in \mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N)$.  In particular, there is nothing mysterious about truth; it is just a mathematical concept formalizable in ZFC like any other mathematical concept.

Comment: Very clear answer. But I think there's one more ambiguity on which one should shed some light. A formalist (such as myself, I think) interprets "The arithmetic sentence $\phi$ is *true*" as "ZFC (formally) proves that $\mathbb{N} \models\phi$" or "$\phi\in\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{PA})$" (where both $\mathbb{N} \models\phi$ and $\phi\in\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{PA})$ are really first-order sentences of ZFC). But with this formalistic definition of truth (lacking a "real world" against which to check truth), which is always relative to a certain metatheory such as ZFC, by Goedel incompleteness...     

Comment: ... of ZFC the alternative "Either $\phi$ is true or $\phi$ is false" doesn't always hold: $\phi\in\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{PA})$ could be undecidable in ZFC (in the sense that ZFC doesn't formally prove "$\phi\in\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{PA})$" nor its negation). Am I saying nonsense? 

Comment: (uh, $\mathrm{Th}(PA)$ should not be typeset in boldface..)

Comment: ϕ∈Th(N) could be undecidable in ZFC; however, ZFC will prove (ϕ∈Th(N))∨(ϕ∉Th(N)). In other words, "either ϕ is true or false" is a theorem of ZFC even if neither ϕ∈Th(N) nor ϕ∉Th(N) is provable in ZFC. Again, there's nothing special about "true sentences of arithmetic" here. ZFC always proves $\psi\vee\neg\psi$ for any $\psi$ regardless of whether $\psi$ or $\neg\psi$ is provable, because ZFC is based on classical logic. I will reiterate that my suggestion here is NOT that "ϕ is true" should be interpreted as "ϕ is provable in ZFC" but as "ϕ∈Th(N)" (for ϕ a first-order sentence of arithmetic).

Comment: By the way, it's wrong to write $\mathrm{Th}(PA)$ (boldface or not!) because by definition, only *structures* (and not *axioms*) can satisfy sentences.

Comment: (Right: I should have written $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{N})$, as in your answer)

Comment: I'm getting confused about undecidability now... I agree that, *from the point of view of ZFC*, $\phi\in\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ is just like any other well formed formula $\psi$. The point is that *from the point of view of arithmetics* "$\phi\in\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{N})$" reads "$\phi$ is true in the real world". (...)


Comment: (...) A ZFC formula like $(\phi\in \mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N))\vee (\phi\notin \mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N))$, on the contrary, doesn't say "a certain sentence is true in the real world" so says nothing about arithmetic 'truths' (Perhaps you can codify it in an exotic way into PA, but it's not the point). So, if we consider an undecidable (in ZFC) sentence of the form $\phi\in\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{N})$, then we must observe that the principle of excluded middle does not hold for "real world truth" about arithmetics. (...)

Comment: (...) It holds formally in ZFC (for trivial reasons: it's in the "logic package" you use to manipulate axioms of ZFC), but it's not "real", as in the "real world" truth is an incomplete concept (by Goedel applied to ZFC). [Of course what said about PA and ZFC also holds for any theory T and metatheory S ].  

Comment: unknowngoogle, I have the same doubts/confusions as you have. But Timothy, I have an even more basic problem: I still don't understand your definition of "ℕ satisfies ϕ. You, and before you Emil, gave me two web-references. I read them, and didn't think I had any problems with them: they use sets in an informal way, not mentioning ZF or any other formalized set theory, and define a model of a theory as a set $M$ with etc., and the satisfability in the model of a formula of the form  $\forall x, \ \phi(x)$ as "for all elements $x$ of $M$, (the interpretation of $\phi(x)$ holds". 

Comment: ...I understand the above in a realist (platonist) way. I know what is a set, what is an element of a set, what it means to test something for all $x$. When I was a graduate student, I took some basic introduction to model theory and this is how I was taught models. But when I get back here, I am told (by Emil, you Timothy, and others) that the model you consider are not "platonist set"
but set of ZF. And then I get (sincerely) confused. For I don't know what is an element of a ZF-set (though I know what means $x \in X$, nor what means "for all" in ZF (though I know $\forall$)...

Comment:  So I really don't understand what you mean when you say, for example "$\exists x:\phi(x)$ is satisfied by $\mathbb{N}$ if 
there exists $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\phi(x)$ is satisfied by $\mathbb{N}$." I am not trying to play the smart ass, I am really requesting help here. The references you and Emil gave me treat the sets as intuitive, non-formal, object, so as a Platonist I have no real problem interpreting what that means, but you keep insisting that it is a formal, syntactic, notion of model, and I don't get it. Thanks for helps (I'm ready to read another ref., if it mentions ZF)...

Comment: @Joël: What you say does not make any sense to me. Both references are as formal as it gets, short of writing down an inscrutable formula in some Coq-like proof assistent. Would you care to give an example of a definition and/or argument that you *do* consider to be formalizable in ZF?

Comment: Or is it simply that you do not understand how to do inductive definitions in ZF? In that case you should consult some textbook on set theory first.

Comment: I should have thought about proof assistants before. Someone has done the work already, of course. A formalization of the definition of the satisfaction relation in Mizar is here: http://mmlquery.mizar.org/cgi-bin/mmlquery/meaning?article=zf_model ("funcnot 4" and subsequent definitions). It is for models of set theory rather than arithmetic, it assumes $\in$ is always interpreted by set membership, and the background theory is Tarski–Grothendieck rather than ZFC, but these are inessential details. It is also perfectly unreadable.

Comment: And here is a proof of the completeness theorem in Isabelle: http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Completeness.shtml . The definition of satisfaction (readable, but quite terse) is in section 3 "Formula", subsection 3.9 "Validity". What’s the background theory is unclear to me (Isabelle is a generic theorem prover).

Comment: @Emil: No, these reference are not formal. For example, in the link given by Tim (end of first paragraph of its Edit above), in the fifth line of the definition of the satisfaction relation, "$\exists x, \phi(x)$" is interpreted as "for some a in A, ...". Now "for some a in A, ..." is not (the beginning of) a statement of ZFC, is it? (or I am getting crazy?). What is a statement of ZFC is
$\exists a \in A, ...$. So please, let us call what I have just said (1) and if you want to answer, tell me if you agree if (1) so that we can have et least this small bit of understanding in common... 

Comment: Now, assuming you agree with (1), my problem with what Tim (and other, including you?) is saying is that he keeps insisting that
he understand models as formal things in ZFC, not as platonistic sets. So perhaps I don't understand what he means by that, but
it seems to me that the interpretation if the model $\mathbb{N}$
of a PA sentence should be a well-formed ZFC sentence. There is no well-formed ZFC beginning by "for some $a$ in $A$". So my understanding (2) is that a PA sentence beginning by $\exists a, ...$ should be interpreted in the model $\mathbb{N}$ as $\exists a \in \mathbb{N},..$. 


Comment: In (2), the first $\exists$ is a symbol of PA, while the second is a symbol of ZFC. So, I am right that my understanding (2) is what Tim or you are saying when you talk of a model is ZFC? No assuming (2) is right, we shall interpret for example the PA sentence $\exists a: a=0$ by $\exists a : a \in \mathbb{N} \wedge a=\emptyset$. (or something like that, I am not familiar with the exact syntax of ZFC. Now I come to my main problem (which may disappear if I have misunderstood (1) or (2)): (3) How do you define the truth value of a ZFC sentence like the one above? ...

Comment: @Joël: No, I don’t agree at all. Everywhere in mathematics, it is quite usual to spell most statements in words, including quantifiers and logical connectives. It would be completely crazy to write everything as a symbolic formula. In any case, it makes no difference, since the two are just different ways of writing the same thing, and you have yourself just admitted that you understand what it means, so the conclusion is that you are only trying to make a point.

Comment: I have been hesitating in my interpretation of what you were saying... At some times my understanding that you meant by truth 
of the sentence in (ZFC) its provability. But Tim and other
have insisted than not. Or it is a definition of truth "by induction" by which I have no idea what you mean in a formal system? 

 



Comment:  I repeat my request: show me a text which does definitions in the way you demand. Since the bulk of modern mathematics is supposed to take place in ZFC, it shouldn’t be hard to find.

Comment: Re (3): You *don’t* define the truth of any ZFC sentences. You are defining the truth of arithmetical sentences in a particular model of arithmetic *inside* ZFC. What is so difficult to understand about this? A set $X$ of reals is open if $\forall x\in X\exists u,v(u<x<v\land(u,v)\subseteq X)$. This is a prefectly usual definition in ZFC. If not, what is your definition of open sets of reals in ZFC, then? If yes, why are you not worried how to define the truth of formulas like $\forall x\in X\exists u,v(u<x<v\land(u,v)\subseteq X)$?

Comment: Emil, my comment five comments above is an example as you requested. Now please stop fighting: I am not criticizing your references or
Tim's and I am a real mathematician asking in good faith. 
If you tell me that in these references "for some a in A" is just a colloquial way to write the formal "\exists a \in A" of ZFC, I agree with you (if only because you're at liberty to make any definition).
So let's move on. Now the interpretation of sentences of PA in the model are formal sentences in ZFC even if we take the liberty to write them in plain english as we usually do in math...

Comment: @Emil. Our two messages crossed each other.  "You are defining the truth of arithmetical sentences in a particular model of arithmetic inside ZFC. What is so difficult to understand about this?".
I don't know. I just don't understand. Note that I would perfectly 
understand the same sentence without the last two words "inside ZFC".
About your assertion about reals: I understand it as a long assertion first defining a set call $\mathbb{R}$ (I guess by the long route
defining $N$, then $Q$, then $R$) and stating that some explicit subset of this set is open as you did. That's just a long...

Comment: formal sentence in ZFC. Except in the very lucky case where you can formally prove it or disprove it, I don't see while this very long sentence of ZFC should have a well-defined truth value any more than say the continuum hypothesis.  

Comment: Joël, you are right that one must distinguish between $\exists$ as a symbol in a first-order formula of arithmetic, and $\exists$ as a quantifier in the formal language of ZFC. To develop the model theory of arithmetic set-theoretically, we must *encode first-order formulas of arithmetic as sets*. For example, we could list the symbols $\exists$, $\neg$, etc., in some fixed order, and agree to encode them with the sets $\lbrace \rbrace, \lbrace\lbrace\rbrace\rbrace$, etc. Formulas would then be sequences of symbols, and sequences can be coded using the Kuratowski ordered-pair trick...

Comment: ...of writing (x,y) as {{x},{x,y}}. Everything—symbols, strings, functions, syntactic rules—must be encoded as sets. Then something like $x\in\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N)$ is a purely set-theoretic statement that can be expressed formally in the language of ZFC. Does that help? – Timothy Chow 0 secs ago

Comment: @unknowngoogle: Classical mathematics assumes that, e.g., either $P=NP$ or $P\ne NP$, regardless of whether we, or the axioms we are willing to assume, can prove either one. If we accept this point of view, then ZFC accurately captures classical mathematical discourse. Now, if for philosophical reasons you don't accept that arithmetic statements can be true independently of whether they can be proved, then you'll reject some of classical math and you shouldn't use ZFC as your meta-theory. E.g., you might want to use IZF instead. See
http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/

Comment: @Tim: yes, definitely. This is not at all how I was understanding 
the phrase "interpret in ZF" so far. Honestly, the web-references
about model-theory we discussed above gave me no hint that such an encoding-process was in play. I will be trying to understand details
of this construction now. Thanks.




Comment: @unknowngoogle: To put it another way, the "little dance" I suggested was for a formalist who wants to make sense of classical mathematics as practiced by classical mathematicians. If you are not only a formalist but also a constructivist who thinks that classical mathematicians are doing something illegitimate when they reason non-constructively, then you must additionally suspend your disapproval of their use of the law of the excluded middle when you're transcribing their journal articles into (say) the Mizar proof assistant.

Comment: Joël: Yes, model theory, like any other piece of mathematics, is written in a human-friendly style, rather than in a style which makes it evident that everything can be built on set theory as a foundation. I suspect that you, like most mathematicians, have glibly accepted that "everything can be based on set theory" without thinking too hard about what that means. If you *do* think about it, you'll see that this means that *everything* you talk about in mathematics—a differential equation, a symbol, a number, a homomorphism, whatever—must be encoded as a set.

Comment: @Joël: for a formalist, there are no sets. There are *sentences* that talk about sets. And, among those, there are *sentences* that talk about sets that *codify* e.g. the following: Riemannian manifolds, the formal theory of groups, the language of linear orders, any number $n$, sentences about natural numbers (and sets thereof), PA (which stands, here, at the same 'level' as the formal theory of groups), $\mathbb{N}$, any model of PA (which stands, here, at the same level as $\mathbb{N}$), $\mathbb{Th}(\mathbb{N})$. 

Comment: [continued]  Wait... how is the latter thing $\mathbb{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ defined? Well, you must have a notion of when a model of PA (such as $\mathbb{N}$) *satisfies* a sentence $\phi$: then $\mathbb{N}\model\phi$ is the formal *sentence* of ZFC (of course written in full fledged unreadable symolism) stating the above, $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ is the *set* of sentences satisfied by $\mathbb{N}$ Wait... but there are no sets! Right: what we can only manipulate is the formal sentence $\phi\in\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ which says this.

Comment: @Joël: I don't know if my comments above have been useful. Anyway, what logicians do is even more "confusing": they formalize [within a certain theory (such as ZFC) which they chose to treat as "the" metatheory] other formal theories of sets (such as ZF or NBG, or even a "copy" of the formal theory ZFC itself), each of which stands at the same "level" (in a hypothetical "who is more meta" hierarchy) as PA or, for what it matters, as any other mathematical object such as $\mathbb{R}^n$. 

Comment: Joel: Ah, I see now that TimothyChow had already clarified the "codifying" thing in a comment. 

Comment: @Timothy: thank you for the link. Maybe you're converting me into a hardcore formalist/intuitionist (for foundational matters)... even if you're not one! ;) But reading your link I'm now wondering how is it possible for a set-theoretic principle (say, foundation) to be incompatible with intuitionistic logic! But this comment thread is getting too long: perhaps I'll open a new question about this in the future.. 

Comment: @Joël: I’m sorry for the tone of some of my comments above. 

Comment: @Emil, Don't worry and thanks for all your explanations.


Comment: @Timothy: your comment yesterday showed me I was on the wrong track
in my attempt to understand the notion of "Model inside ZFC", and a good night over this gave me a full understanding of what you meant.
I was actually misled by the phrase "Model inside ZFC" into believing that just the model was a ZFC-set, while actually you interpret everything (the language, the theory, the model) as sets in the
ZFC axiomatic. Now everything is clear, so thanks again.

Comment: PS: this thread has already been too long, but if you're interested in what was my problem you can read this. Consider a language with just two constant $c$ and $c'$ and a theory on this language with no
non-logical axioms. Let us consider a model $M$ of that theory defined as the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with $c$ interpreted as the empty set, $c'$ the set of even integers $>2$
that are not some of two primes. Does $M$ satisfies $c=c'$?
With the platonistic interpretation of model's theory (sets as naturel sets outside any axioms system), Goldbach conjecture is either true or false...

Comment: and $M$ satisfies $c=c'$ accordingly. My problem was that when I interpreted $M$ as a set in ZFC as I was told to do, Goldbach conjecture could be indecidable and has no truth value, so I found meaningless to say "$M$ satisfies $c=c'$" if "Golbach's conjecture 
is true in ZFC". Now, you solved my problem by telling me to 
interpret everithing insided ZFC. For example, $Th(N)$ for any model $N$ would be a
ZFC-set of sentences in the language (defined ultimately in terms of $\emptyset$), either empty or equal to $\{"c-c'"\}$, and in this case $Th(M)$ could be defined...

Comment: ...as the complement in $\{"c=c'"\}$ of the image of the set of
integers $>2$ that are not sumo two primes by the constant map
that sends everything to "$c=c'$". This is a perfectly valid construction in ZFC, and we thus have a well-defined set
$Th(M)$ in ZFC, even if ZFC perhaps cannot provably determine wether this set has cardinality $0$ or $1$. So I believe this is what you 
meant and I am satisfied with that answer. Thanks again.
PPS: @unknowngoogle: by all means do open a new question...



Answer (score 8):

We can avoid the issue of truth by simply proving the following statement:

> There is no Turing machine which,
>   given a statement S, returns TRUE if S
>   is provable in PA, returns FALSE if
>   NOT(S) is provable in PA, and returns
>   either TRUE or FALSE for all S.

Philosophers can then argue about what truth means. As long as you believe that PA is <strike>consistent</strike> true, and that every statement is either true or false, this shows that a Turing machine cannot capture truth. A formalist may not agree with this interpretation of the above statement, but they certainly will agree that this statement is meaningful.

UPDATE: See discussion below of whether what a person who thinks PA is consistent, but not true, might make of this answer.

Comment: The belief necessary for this to work is not merely that PA is consistent but that it is true.  A consistent theory might prove false statements.  So there would be a problem if philosophers came up with a notion of truth such that some PA axioms aren't true.  The problem could be alleviated by using weaker theories in place of PA, but really obstinate philosophers might still be a problem.  

Comment: David, that's great. I'll try to write a proof for my own sake of your statement, but I am confident it is true (and provable).
Moreover it is simple.  

Comment: This certainly gives a statement that almost any formalist would agree with, but to elaborate a bit on what Andreas Blass said, it's not a plausible *interpretation* of the original sentence, and it's not even a weakening of the original sentence unless you assume that theorems of PA are true.  Truth and provability are not the same, and it may cause confusion later down the line to think that whenever one sees "true" one can replace it with "provable" to get a "formalist version" of the statement.

Comment: First of all, I'm surprised this answer was chosen. I thought Timothy Chow's was clearly better, and that this was a less good alternative perspective. That said, while I certainly understand that truth and provability are different, I don't see what is wrong with describing some properties we would want truth to have: True statements are consistent with each other, the axioms of PA are true, and so forth, and then demonstrate that no Turing computable property has those features. That isn't a weakening of the statement that truth isn't Turing computable; it's a strengthening!

Comment: Would it help to make an analogy to Arrow's theorem? Arrow roughly says that there is no fair voting method; and makes that precise by giving a list of features any fair voting method should have. Similarly, I am giving a list of features that any notion of truth should satisfy. I'm not saying this is what truth is, just like Arrow isn't saying that any method that satisfies these features is fair, he's just saying that these features already rule out existence (or, in my case, rule out Turing computability.) 

Comment: Probably part of my mental block here is that, while I could imagine someone who suspected there might be a technical difficulty in PA, I have trouble imagining someone who doesn't think that PA should be true, and that any technical flaw is an error in how we have encoded our intuition about finite sets into our axioms. That sounds to me like someone who thinks that there is nothing unfair about a voting system with a dictator.

Comment: @David and Timothy: first, thanks to both of you (and to the other)
for your patience in dealing with my question. Second, now I am not so sure why I have chosen David's answer. Actually, at the beginning I had a very clear idea of what I would have accepted as an answer,
and then I lost energy in sterile fights with people willing to close 
the question, and when I accepted this answer this morning it was in part out of exhaustion. David's answer is very nice but as Tim says it's not exactly what I asked. I am recovering and will refrain from commenting anymore until I get all my ideas back. 

Comment: David, please apologize: while I really appreciate your answer,
now that I understand Timothy's answer I realize that this is the one
which really solves my deepest problems (relating to the question 
asked, that is). So I accepted his answer finally. 

Answer (score 5):

Well, suppose you believe in the notion of consistency of theories of arithmetic. Then I believe you can define the notion of truth. In particular, any simple universal statement is "true" if and only if adding it to PA produces a consistent system. (If it were "false", there would be a counterexample constructible in finite time.)

The statement "There is no algorithm for deciding whether adding simple universal statements to PA produces a consistent system" is true and, with this partial definition of truth, implies the quoted statement.

Another version is this:

There is no algorithm for sorting first-order statements into a boxe labeled "true" and a boxe labeled "false" such that the negation of each statement in the "false" box is in the "true" box and the set of statements in the "true" box is consistent.

Comment: So you define "true" as "non-refutable" in a given theory 
of arithmetic (say PA, to fix ideas). That's a notion even the most formalist mathematician can understood.
And I understand that your statement  "There is no algorithm for deciding if a first-order statement about numbers is non-refutable in (PA)" is correct. I note that with your notion of
truth there well be a statement true in your sense but that a platonist would call plainly false (for example, the negation of Geodel's "true and undecidable" statement) but this is of course unavoidable. Thanks for your answer.


Comment: @Joël: The negation of Gödel’s formula is not a universal statement, but an existential one.

Comment: Actually that's not quite what my definition means, sorry for the confusion. I'm saying that "true" = "non-refutable" for a specific class of statements, those I think are usually called $\Pi_1$ statement. These consist of a universal quantifier around something that is checkable (provable or disprovable) in finite time.

The negation of a Godel statement has an existential quantifier.

The idea of this is that this is the class of statements in which the Platonist notion of truth is most easily translated into fomralism, and even on that limited class the theorem is proved.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I overlooked that you only defined "true" in the particular case of a  simple universal statement. You affirm
that you can defined it for all first-order statement though, am I correct? I have to say I am getting more and more confused:
in answer to my question, I have been referred to three notions
of truth, but none with sufficient explanations of definitions.
They were: the Tarski's notion of proof (with a long reference that I am soon going to read), your notion of truth that you explained for
a universal statement but not in general, and the notion mentioned by Emil...
 


Comment: ...and Ed in comments under the question. What are the relations between those three notions of truth for a first order statement about numbers? Are they the same? If so, I should really have known it.  In any case, can you give me more reference (or even better, more explanations) about them.

Joel


Comment: Tarski’s definition is the usual definition in model theory which I referred to above (except that the SEP article describes in a rather long-winded way its philosophical ramifications instead of properly giving the actual definition). Will’s definition is also equivalent, but it only works for a restricted set of sentences ($\Pi^0_1$). On the other hand, it has the advantage that it is expressible within the arithmetical language itself. ...

Comment: ...  One can generalize this idea to get inside the language of arithmetic the definition of truth for sentences of bounded quantifier complexity ($\Sigma^0_k$ for a fixed $k$). This is the best one can do, since by Tarski’s theorem on undefinability of truth, the full truth predicate for arithmetic is not expressible in the arithmetical language.

Comment: My definition should be equivalent only for the minimal model of the theory. Especially in arithmetic, the minimal model is usually the one we care about. (Also I think in other formal systems a minimal model may not even exist).

Comment: Well, your definition is actually equivalent in every model of arithmetic that satisfies the uniform $\Sigma^0_1$-reflection principle for PA. Now, there is no reason to refer to PA in the definition, you can instead use Robinson’s arithmetic Q. This modified definition only relies on the $\Sigma^0_1$-reflection principle for Q, hence it works in every model of PA, and in fact, in every model of the much weaker theory $I\Delta_0+\mathrm{SUPEXP}$. (If you further replace “consistent” with “cut-free consistent”, you can get it down to $I\Delta_0+\mathrm{EXP}$, which is about optimal.)

Answer (score 4):

"True" in this context surely refers to Tarski's [inductive definition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/) of truth.

Answer (score 2):

I would take the sentence to mean something like:

Given any model of PA in any axiomatic system, there is no Turing machine that ... according to whether the sentence is true or false for that model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not think that it solves the problem: You need to be a super-platonist to believe to the notion of truth in a model: that is, you need to believe in the absolute existence of sets, not just of integers.


Comment: No i don't need to believe in the absolute existence of sets - only the axiom system in which the model is constructed needs to believe in the absolute existence of sets.  "True or false for that model" means "true or false for that model according to that axiomatic system".  (Since I am not a Platonist, that's all it could mean!)  (Yes the sentence could be undecidable, but one could just extend the axiomatic system - I guess one has to careful about the order of quantifiers to allow the axiomatic system to be extended after the statement is chosen.)


Comment: Thanks, I now understand that your answer is more or less equivalent to the other ones I received, and I need to read more in the link Emil gave me to be sure I understand them all, and then to see if I can accept them. I'll try to do that tonight. But meanwhile, let me just say that you put the finger exactly on where I have a problem with. Roughly speaking, you guys all define true as true in a model of arithmetic in set theory. But either you interpret the truth in this model as some absolute platonistic truth and we are not better than at the beginning...
or you interpret it as what is  

Comment: Or we interpret it as "provability" in some axiomatic of set theory,
but then we get the problem that there will always be undecidable statement, that is with your definition, statements that are neither nor true nor false, and then what the algorithm we are talking about
is suppose to do when such a statement is fed to it as input?
So you say we can change our axiomatic of set theory to get rid of in decidable statement, but as you say it is a little tricky (plus it is not canonical) and I need to understand exactly what we're
doing here.




Comment: How about, "Given any axiomatic system X containing a model M of PA and any Turing machine T that takes first order sentences as input and produces TRUE or FALSE, there exists an axiomatic system Y extending X and a sentence A such that Y proves one answer for the interpretation of A in M and T gives the other answer on A."

Comment: I suppose I should insist that Y is relatively consistent with X.